# Badge activity roll-up on profile page isn't consistent

Tags: bug, profile-page, recent-activity

If a user is awarded the same badge more than once in quick succession, the profile's activity tab will show each badge if the "badges" filter is selected...

[image: "badges" filter showing three similar badges]

...but the "all" filter will roll them up into a single entry...

[image: "all" filter showing only one badge]

...only not consistently:

[image: "all" filter showing both badges]

Shouldn't the roll-up behaviour for the "all" filter of the activity tab be consistent across badges? Given that the badge details page works the same way for both of these badges, I can't explain away the difference in presentation.

Also, if the desired behaviour is to roll the badge entries up into a single item in these cases, shouldn't the interface indicate that roll-up happened?

[image: amended roll-up entry]