# Badge awarded twice just showing once in activity tab

Tags: bug, profile-page, recent-activity

Yesterday I got two Enlightened badges at the same moment (I guess that someone saw two answers of me with score of 9 and upvoted them within an exact minute).

Now I see that in [my activity tab -> "all"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui?tab=activity&sort=all&page=3) it just appears once, while in the [ativity tab -> "badges"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui?tab=activity&sort=badges) appears twice.

Shouldn't it appear the same number of times in both cases?

Note that the activity tab is having other problems, as I commented in [Activity summary showing actions with Community creation date](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/193955/209901).

---

These are the notifications I got:

> [image]

And here is a screenshot of the activity when filtered by "all":

> [image]

Comment: Is it possible that you just got the notification twice?

Comment: @danielhanly.com just posted an image with the notifications I got.

Comment: I also think it's a bug, added screenshot to reduce chances of people misunderstanding the issue. :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Badge activity roll-up on profile page isn't consistent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130981/badge-activity-roll-up-on-profile-page-isnt-consistent)

Answer (score 1):

Badges are awarded during scheduled tasks. You had two posts at a score of 9 which were up-voted between runs, thus making them both eligible for the nice answer badge. Coincidentally, this made both posts eligible for the enlightened badge, which was also awarded.

I think the confusion is that the notifications are grouped by *badge* and not by *post*, since the tasks that award badges run serially. One ran, you got nice answer twice, then the other ran giving you enlightened twice.

As the jobs send notifications as they run, you get them in the order they were sent.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, Tim Post. Maybe I didn't explain it properly, but the "buggy" thing I found is that the "Enlightened" badge appears once in ["all"](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui?tab=activity&sort=all&page=3) but twice in ["badges"](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui?tab=activity&sort=badges)

Comment: It is inconsistent, (would probably be cured if a 'x 2' was tacked on to that), but I'm pretty sure still by design. I won't attach a status tag to this, however - on the off chance that this is a bug (pretty sure I did misunderstand you)

Comment: The fact that the two "nice answer" badges _do_ show up as separate entries kind of highlights the inconsistency.

Comment: Something similar happened again: I gained the "Nice Answer" twice within 10 hours, without any other activity from me in the meantime. Then, the badge just appears once in my activity: http://stackexchange.com/users/2251762/fedorqui?tab=activity whereas in the [SO] activity it does show twice: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui?tab=activity&sort=all